# Adição de HTML no Rodapé da Loja Integrada

Tags: jquery, html

Olá, pessoal!
Tudo bem?

Recentemente, iniciei no meio do e-market e criei minha loja virtual via Loja Integrada.Estou tentando realizar alguns ajustes no template que comprei, adequando ele às  minhas necessidades, mas sou novato no ramo de codificação.

Estou tentando colocar algumas informações no rodapé da página, mas sem sucesso.
Eis o código abaixo:

```
$("#rodape .institucional .container .row-fluid .span4").append(
    "<li class=\"email\">" +
        "<p><i class=\"fa fa-envelope\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>
            atendimento@amoremmesa.com </p>" +
    "<li>" +
    "<li class=\"endereco-loja\">" +
        "<span class=\"endereco\">" + 
        "<p><i class=\"fa fa-home\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> Teste de Endereço </p>" +
        "</span>" +
    "<li>");
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a elucidar esse mistério do porquê de não estar funcionando?
Obrigado e abraços.

Answer (score 1):

### Pontos em atenção e possíveis melhorias:

- O email tem vários espaços antes do próprio texto que entram em conflito com o funcionamento do código, por isso que ele não está a funcionar. Mas isso resolve-se eliminando todos os espaços anteriores e juntando-o à linha anterior de maneira a fique tudo numa só linha (sem quebras de linha).
- Para evitares de colocar uma barra de escapamento `\` a cada aspas (`" "`) que encontras em cada `class/id` que apareça, basta escreveres o HTML normalmente e no final de cada linha trocar o símbolo de `+` por uma barra de escapamento - **`\`** como irás ver no exemplo abaixo do resultado final do teu código corrigido e em funcionamento.
- Existem elementos que não estão devidamente encerrados `</>`.

### Código em funcionamento:

```js
$('#rodape').append(
'<li class="email">\
  <p><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>atendimento@amoremmesa.com</p>\
</li>\
<li class="endereco-loja">\
  <span class="endereco">\
    <p><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Teste de Endereço </p>\
  </span>\
</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="rodape">
  Rodapé institucional container
</div>
```